# Cannot access websites on a certain hosted virtual server from office, but website ok for anywhere else

Tags: networking, website

I have several sites hosted on a virtual server from a hosting company. All computers can access the site except our office since last week. IE status bar shows waiting for the site but then "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" error

I have tried:
1. telnet mysite.com 80 return with a blank screen and underscore prompt, which seems normal to me when I telnet other sites
2. use ip on browser instead of domain name, does not work
3. tracert, trace seems normal like all other sites
4. WireShark looking for http traffic with that domain name or ip, this is strange as nothing can be found, no traffic record shown, but when I tried other sites, traffic are found either using domain name filter or ip filter expression

I have tried disable anti-virus but still it is not working.

Comment: Do you have any firewalls enabled on the virtual server?

Comment: No blocking as I was told by the support of the hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

So telnet on 80 works but IE doesn't? Try another browser, could be an IE setting/issue. Also remember to pay attention to whether you're putting in "www" or not.

Comment: it is not a browser issue as we have different browser in the office all don't work.